# How do I disable fullpage cache on Product View page?

Tags: xml, full-page-cache

Hi this is my config xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config>
            <modules>
                <Test_Disablefullpage>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
                </Test_Disablefullpage>
            </modules>
            <global>
                <models>
                    <test_disablefullpage>
                        <class>Test_Disablefullpage_Model</class>
                    </test_disablefullpage>
                </models>
                <frontend>
                    <events>
                        <controller_action_predispatch>
                            <observers>
<test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                                    <class>test_disablefullpage/observer</class>
                                    <method>disableCache</method>
                           </test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                            </observers>
                        </controller_action_predispatch>
                    </events>
                </frontend>

            </global>
        </config>
```

This is my Observer.php file from the model folder:

```
class Test_Disablefullpage_Model_Observer
{
    public function disableCache(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        echo 1 ; exit();
        // Check to see if $action is a Product controller
        if ($action instanceof Mage_Catalog_ProductController) {
            $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();

            // Tell Magento to 'ban' the use of FPC for this request
            $cache->banUse('full_page');
        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss smth ? Or why I do not get the echo 1 exit() when I access the Product View page ? My guess that I didn't use the right event. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not calling the right event as you suspected.

Try this event instead: `catalog_controller_product_view`

So it becomes this:

```
    <frontend>
                    <events>
                        <catalog_controller_product_view>
                            <observers>
<test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                                    <class>test_disablefullpage/observer</class>
                                    <method>disableCache</method>
                           </test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                            </observers>
                        </catalog_controller_product_view>
                    </events>
                </frontend>
```

Full list of events here: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

**[UPDATE]**

Also change your observer function as follow:

```
public function disableCache(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

    Mage::log('got called', null, 'my_log.log');
}
```

This will create one file called `my_log.log` in your `var/log` folder. That means, your observer is fired.

**[UPDATE 2]**

Keep your `<frontend>` tag outside of `<global>`

```
<global>
       .....
      </global>

      <frontend>
                <events>
                    <catalog_controller_product_view>
                        <observers
       <test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                                <class>test_disablefullpage/observer</class>
                                <method>disableCache</method>
                       </test_disablefullpage_controller_action_predispatch_catalog_controller_product_view>
                        </observers>
                    </catalog_controller_product_view>
                </events>
            </frontend>
```

Comment: Thx you , but I already tried it and still nothing I do not get the echo 1; exit(), result. Any other idea ? :)

Comment: instead doing `echo 1; exit()` can you do, `echo "1"; die();`

Comment: I did, but still nothing changed

Comment: Sometime, echo doesn't work in observer, can you create a log file instead. Plez check my updated answer.

Comment: I did, there is no any my_log.log file in the var/log. I guess I didn't get there. Smth is wrong with my xml  config

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35486/discussion-between-chester-and-adarsh-khatri).